# Batch change image Luminosity in Photoshop

Tags: image, batch-processing, photoshop, photography, luminance

I have about 2000 images with different values of luminosity. I can, of course, open each one and manually change Luminosity until it reaches my desired value (200), but of course when you have 2000 images that's not an option. It seems I can't record an action, because as far as I know there is no way to directly change Luminosity to a particular discrete value. Is there?

Comment: Hi Andre, If you don't have any luck here try reposting your question at: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop

Comment: Thanks! Just posted there!

Comment: What do you mean by *"with different values of luminosity"*? Where are you looking to see a single luminosity value for an image?